# What are good screen settings by which I can reduce eye strain?

Tags: display-settings, eye-strain

I play computer games. I also watch TV series on my smart phone and TV. I also often have to read a lot between every 2-3 days. Sometimes, playing games for just 4 hours a day lead to a headache to me.

I have already installed f.lux in my computer and Eye Filter Protector app in my smartphone both of which seem to filter out blue light from the screen. But still watching TV series with each episode of 20 minutes in my smart phone leads to eye strain with the Eye Filter Protector app being on in back ground. f.lux in my computer does not seem to be activated when I am playing computer games.

What are some ways by which I can tweak my screen settings in both computer and smartphone to reduce eye strain? Does going to monochromacy in screen settings reduce eye strain?

Does using computer and smartphone less can help?

Comment: To me it sounds more like you need glasses or getting your current glasses adjusted. I had the same problem before I got my glasses.

Comment: If you're getting eyestrain, the best setting is "off".  As Adam says in his answer, this is really too much if an individual thing for other people to have a definitive answer on what will be best for you.  Random suggestions aren't really a good fit for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more along the lines of individualistic differences, by which I mean that I can stare at any screen for 20 hours daily without headaches. You sound on the other side of the 'spectrum'. Everyone is different, so we can't really expect a single answer to your situation.

You'll most likely have to play with the settings for yourself, and see what works. Try playing with screen brightness, font size (stick with clear easy to read fonts), working with the screens into your day in short increments, perhaps try a negative contrast - black becomes white, and white becomes black.

Heck, maybe even try just tilting your screen to an odd angle. Try all the things you can think of, and let your instinct develop new ideas to try.